# symfony display image thumbnail for file in private directory

Tags: symfony, gallery, private

I have Symfony 6.2 application in which logged user may upload images to server. Because images are non public, I upload this images to /var/images directory.
In config/services.yaml I have

```
parameters:
    card_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/images'
```

and for upload service I use

```
    App\Service\ImageUploader:
        arguments:
            $targetDirectory: '%card_directory%'
```

upload images is function.
But now I need serve this images to twig template for generating 4 column thumnail gallery. How I should generate path to this images in twig templates?

Finally I use this code for server private images with Controller for Card entity, which has image

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Card;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ServePrivateImageController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Returns a private image for card file for display.
     *
     * @Route("/serve-private-image/{id}", name="serve_private_image", methods="GET")
     * @param Card $card
     * @return BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function privateImageServe(Card $card): BinaryFileResponse
    {
        return $this->fileServe($card->getImage());
    }
    /**
     * Returns a private file for display.
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return BinaryFileResponse
     */
    private function fileServe(string $path): BinaryFileResponse
    {
        $absolutePath = $this->getParameter('card_directory') . '/' . $path;

        return new BinaryFileResponse($absolutePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, the directory (and therefore the images) are not public - you cannot generate a path. Therefore you will need to create a controller to fetch and serve those images.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you would simply refer to your route within twig.

```
<div class="row">
{% for file in files %}
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="{{ path('serve_private_image', {id: file.id}) }}" />
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But as far as serving the resized images, LiipImageBundle does what you're looking for, and much more:

https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle

Although it takes a few minutes to set up (because of the integration with flysystem), once it's working you can even keep your (secure) images on s3 and it handles all the downloading and local caching, rotating the resized issues, etc.